# Что значит эта строка?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Эта строка показывает количество итемов которые хранит в себе Cursor?

```
 userCursor =  db.rawQuery("select * from "+ DatabaseHelper.TABLE, null);
header.setText("Найдено элементов: " + String.valueOf(userCursor.getCount()));
```

Comment: нужно больше кода)

Comment: добаил)ппересмотрите )

Comment: как я понел курсор получил данные обьекта и getCount(): получает количество извлеченных из базы данных объектов  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int getCount ()` Returns the numbers of rows in the cursor. То есть возвращает количество строк в курсоре

[Источник](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getCount())

Comment: спасибо очень помоги